# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to send a message to a specific channel, I followed the steps of discord on how to do it I followed their steps correctly but it aint work.
Here is the steps I followed http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel

and here is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("A member just joined and his name is" + member.name)
    general = bot.get_channel(466675715333554179)
    mid = member.id
    await general.send('Welcome <@%s> to OnePlix server, I am Cooler!' % (mid))
```

Comment: what was the full error

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ezter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ezter\Desktop\Oneplix bot\Bot.py", line 45, in on_member_join
    await general.send('Welcome <@%s> to OnePlix server, I am Cooler!' % (mid))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: The error is telling you `general` is `None`, but your code is assuming it's not `None`.

Comment: If you run `import discord; print(discord.__version__)`, what does it print?

Comment: You're presumably running the currently-stable/-public version of discord.py, in which all IDs are strings. Wrap that channel ID in quote marks and see if it works.

Comment: I did the quote I get the same error except that the 'NoneType' turnes into 'Channel'

Comment: And the version is 0.16.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a stupid mistake. I entered the FAQ of the wrong discord.py version.

The solution is this

```
await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='12324234183172'), 'hello')
```

Comment: You probably want to use the second method there: `await client.send_message(client.get_channel('12324234183172'), 'hello')`.  The `Object` class resolving items based on their ids works, but it's really easy to lose track of what the type of that object should be, espescially when your bots start getting large.